# Python - Selenium - Web Driver - change page in the website

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get through the pages.
In the code below I just managed to select the "Search" button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from BeautifulSoup import *
import urllib
import re

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.citius.mj.pt/portal/consultas/consultascire.aspx')

searchButton = browser.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch').click()
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I wan't build a scrap script in order to extract the info from the site.

Comment: I wan't build a scrap script in order to extract the info from the site. https://www.citius.mj.pt/portal/consultas/consultascire.aspx using python and selenium webdriver, but i'm only able to open the browser and find the element "button search" . After push the search I need to walk throw the different web pages 1,2,3,4...., i think i find the element ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Pager1$btnNextPage but when i replicate the code iqual to the search button doesn't workk, hope this was more clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: I find the way, wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 100) need to finish the load of the website and then click in the button